# nslookup can't find server

Tags: dns, google-dns

My Linux host name is Jenkins, but why it can't find it?

```
admin@Jenkins:~$ nslookup Jenkins
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find Jenkins: NXDOMAIN
```

I googled and found 8.8.8.8. is Google DNS server. How can I configure it to use as my DNS server? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: because you are looking up an internal host with external dns server?

Comment: It looks like. I am not even aware of the 8.8.8.8 server. How to resolve my IP to the host name Jenkins?

Comment: You should set your Linux PC DNS server point to your router (assume you have one)

Answer (score 0):

Odds are that your host is in your home.

If is your home network, then your router which is most likely provided by your ISP, you can add your hostname to that router dns server.

Try browsing to 192.168.1.1 and browse for DNS and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you have your own DNS, then go to network settings on Ubuntu and switch interface from DHCP to `manual` and set IP,mask,gateway and DNS that know about your host (FQDN <-> IP)